# I can't run my RN project because gradle problem

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run my RN project then this error appears, maybe someone knows how to fix it?
I've tried several methods in other threads but it still doesn't work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWiiV.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PurY.jpg)

please if that has a way out

Comment: Please do not add pictures, instead copy the error inside the question

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to `gradle.properties`

```
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx512m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
```